# Sharepoint 2013 App Server2 Product Configuration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, central-administration

I have installed SharePoint 2013 set up in my app server2.Now i am running prodct config wizard in apps server 2.When i running the product config wizard,its showing few option like "Do not use this machine to host web site" and "Use this machine to host the web site".

What is the difference between that two?

which option i have to choose in my apps server2 product config wizard.

Comment: is it first server or 2nd server in the farm?

Comment: second apps server

Answer (score 1):

This is referring to Host the Central admin site. You get this option when you add another server in the farm.

**Do not use this machine to host web site** means this server will not host Central admin web site and not provisioned it on the server.

**Use this machine to host the web site** means this server will be host the Central admin site, So now you can have multiple central admin site in your farm.

we use this option mostly when we want to move central admin on different server or configure as High availability.

If you want to provision the CA on 2 servers, then you select the Use option others use dont.

Comment: What is the advantage of having CA in 2 servers?How about URL of both the CA...if one CA down means another one will be available?

Comment: if you use the loadbalncer then yes if one goes down then 2nd will be available. even no load balancer and no fqdn then you can access the central admin from both server via servername :portnumber...http://www.harbar.net/articles/spca.aspx i dont see any advantage having 2 CA.

Answer (score 0):

This is referring to the Central Administration web site.
If you want to use this server to host the Central Administration web site, then choose "Use this machine to host the web site".
If you do not want this machine to host the Central Administration web site, then choose "Do not use this machine to host web site".
Note that you can have more than one server running the Central Administration web site, but by default when launching Central Administration, the farm will connect to the first machine in the farm that hosted the Central Administration web site.